# What does a witch do when hexing someone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Some [hexes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch#TOC-Hex) (like [Cackle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-cackle-su) or [Charm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-charm-su)) specify some form of action to be taken by the witch when activating them, but most hexes do not specify, does the witch just look someone and then the hex is active?
Can anyone notice when someone is being hexed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It Depends on the Hex

A witch's [hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch#TOC-Hex) is either an [extraordinary ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Extraordinary-Abilities-Ex-) if labeled *(Ex)*, a [spell-like ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) if labeled *(Sp)*, or a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) if labeled *(Su)*.

In general, unless noted otherwise, none of these require the creature to perform certain obvious gestures, chant magic words, or employ dime-store trinkets to make an effect happen. In the witch's case, unless a hex notes otherwise, using a hex is a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity (the specific case of the witch's hex overriding the general nature of spell-like abilities which usually provoke attacks of opportunity).

That means a hex that doesn't note otherwise has no visible effect, makes no sound, doesn't require the witch to pull a funny face or heckle her target, or anything. The witch can--if not noted otherwise--merely take a standard action and watch the results.

For example, the hex [discord](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-discord-su) says

> The witch can make an animal or humanoid within 30 feet distrust another creature within line of sight. The target's attitude toward the other creature decreases by one step. A successful Will save negates this effect. The effect lasts for a number of rounds equal to the witch's Intelligence modifier. The duration can be extended with the cackle hex. Whether or not the save is successful, a creature cannot be the target of this hex again for 1 day. At 8th level, this effect decreases the attitude of the target creature by two steps.
>
> This is a mind-affecting charm effect.

The witch stares and discord happens. No one but the witch--and those aware of magic being used in the area--knows that the witch has done anything or that magic has been used. Everyone only knows that the witch spent about 3 seconds, apparently, doing nothing.

Other creatures should *not* be able to note when a witch is using a hex that's an extraordinary ability (e.g. the hex [child-scent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-child-scent-ex)) unless the hex says so (e.g. the hex [nails](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-nails-ex)). Hexes that are spell-like abilities and supernatural abilities--as explicitly magical effects--*can* be detected by effects that detect magic (e.g. the spell [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic)), but such hexes explicitly *aren't* spells, therefore, for example, the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft) is of no help in their identification.

A creature who succeeds on its saving throw versus a witch's hex that's a spell-like ability or supernatural ability may know--if the DM considers such an effect *close enough* to a spell (as I do of any spell-like ability and supernatural ability)--that it's been the target of a hostile magical effect, feeling ["a hostile force or a tingle, [yet it] cannot deduce the exact nature of the attack."](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw)

## Individual Witches May Vary

However, witches can always employ *false* components when using the class feature hex, gesturing, using witchy language, and throwing eyes of newt at folks. This might even be a good idea, as townsfolk may consider the witch helpless when they get the drop on the witch, tie her up, and prepare her for burning at the stake. Then, [when the townsfolk noses fall off and their legs run away or whatever](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48116/8610), they might not even realize it's the bound, gagged, eye-of-newt-less witch doing the hexing.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no action described, then it's up to the witch to decide exactly how she performs the hex in question. A hex takes a standard action to use and does not provoke an AoO (under normal circumstances) which suggests that the action taken is normally either innocuous or at the very least not particularly noteworthy or complex, at least until your nose falls off and your legs run away or whatever is about to happen to you.

For the purpose of identifying the use of and nature of a hex, I'd recommend adjudicating a Knowledge (arcana) check **provided the witch wants it to be ambiguous.** As hexes like Cackle demonstrate, some witches just really want to savor your reaction. If that's the case, then yes, anyone can notice because the witch wants them to.

Anyway, that's my two cents on the matter. I hope it helps.