# Are targets aware if they are being hexed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, witch

If a creature is the target of a witch hex, such as Evil Eye, Slumber, or Charm, are they aware that they have been targeted?

Would they be able to determine who hexed them?

Does it matter if the target passed their save or not?

Comment: See if questions remain after reading this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48115/8610).

Comment: So it seems to depend on the hex, but otherwise there not any V S M components. That's pretty slick. Damn witches are powerful.

Comment: Shall I mark this question as a duplicate, or are there questions that remain unanswered?