# Are casters aware of when their summons are dismissed by any effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning

If a caster has summoned a monster or creature, are they aware when it gets dismissed either by magic like dispel magic or if its "killed" by damage? Not what caused it, just that the summon(s) is gone?

Comment: This is answered in an answers to another of your questions [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93523/8610), yet this question isn't a duplicate of that earlier one. In what way does this situation lead you to believe answers will be different?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I didnt think of the spells in the same way, but you are correct in that it does answer my question.