# Do you always notice if a spell affecting you is dispelled?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If someone with an ongoing spell on them has that spell dispelled, do they automatically know that the spell is no longer affecting them?

Obviously if the spell is noticeable (*fireshield*, *fly*, *light*, etc) they would notice the effects being gone, but what about something like *protection from energy* or the like?

Is the answer different depending on whether the target was the one who cast the dispelled spell or not? (ie does casting a spell on yourself give you more information about its status than if it was cast by someone else?)

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93523/8610)

Answer (score 6):

Nothing in *D&D 3.5* that I've found gives a creature *more* knowledge of spells it casts than what the *Player's Handbook* says a creature knows about the spells it casts.

What the *Player's Handbook* does *not* say is that a creature has *special* knowledge of a spell if the creature is that spell's caster. There's usually no indication to the caster—or anyone else—that a spell with no perceptible effect has run its course, been suppressed, or been dispelled. Trial and error and the ability to detect magical auras are the only actual indicators that such a spell's effect is ongoing.

A *specific* spell may indicate otherwise, of course—for example, the caster knows when a creature triggers her *alarm* spell, but absent a personal exception to the contrary a caster does *not* know when her *alarm* spell's been disabled, dispelled, or suppressed. Similarly, for example, this means that a caster usually doesn't know until it's too late that her *protection from energy* spell has been dispelled.

However, a DM should be cautious and consistent about this lest he alienate players. Explaining at a new campaign's start that this is how spells work in this campaign is much less stressful than trying to implement such rules in an *ongoing* campaign wherein the players had previously been given perfect knowledge of their spells!

In this DM's campaigns, a caster *does* have perfect knowledge of a spell's remaining duration if that duration is neither instantaneous nor permanent, this DM assuming that part of caster training is keeping such a precise mental stopwatch and saving this DM from having to do that bookkeeping.